# Can I prevent DataDog from closing OpsGenie incidents?

Tags: datadog, opsgenie

The question is about DataDog - OpsGenie integration. Whenever a DataDog monitor triggers an alert an incident is opened in OpsGenie (which is good), but when the monitor recovers back to a healthy state the OpsGenie incident is auto-closed (which is bad).

Is there any way to prevent this behavior? I want to keep incidents open until they are acked and resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allowing 'triggered' (but not 'recovery') monitor notifications is not a configurable option for the integration on either Opsgenie or Datadog.

You *can*, however, control this within the Datadog Monitor message body where you reference opsgenie

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet @opsgenie-oncall @slack-somechannel

You can wrap the opsgenie reference within the message body with conditional tags (datadog actually calls them variables) documented here:
https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/notifications/?tab=is_alert#conditional-variables
Then the message body might look something like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet {{#is_alert}}@opsgenie-oncall{{/is_alert}} @slack-somechannel

Now the alert to opsgenie will only occur on the 'trigger' of the monitor but not on 'recovery'